# Export of binary data (for example binary files) into a string with .NET?

Tags: .net, import, export, binary-data, text-formatting

How can I convert/export **binary data** (for example binary files like excel- or word-documents) into a **string** (into text format) in **.NET**, so that it can be imported somewhere else (e.g. in another application, which was written in another programming language (not in .NET)).
Are there **universal concepts** to achieve this goal ?

Comment: You should look at Ascii85: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85. Any such solution, however, needs support in both applications, so if you want to pass that string to another application that already exists, I would look at what that application supports.

Comment: Depending on your target client there are lot of ways to do it especially if you want to optimize as you know witch character (if any) can't be transported. But as jon said, base64 is the most common one since it is used in all mail systems (MIME also define quoted printable but for purely binary data it's notably worse than base64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common form is to use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding between binary and text. .NET supports this with [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

Base64 is widely supported, and is a common way of encoding binary data in pure ASCII, encoding 3 bytes into 4 characters (repeatedly).